# how to: date of loading minus 4 days in CSL

Tags: xml, xslt

We would like to know how to solve the following problem.

For sending certain emails, stylesheets have been designed using XSL version 1.0

Here we want to make a timestamp minus 4 days visible in the email, but this does not seem possible. does somebody know how we can solve this?

Example: loadingdate = 2022-05-19 14:57:00 and the result we want to see back in the stylesheet is this timestamp - 4 days which results in: 2022-05-15

We use XSL version 1.0 and the code that we use to get the loading date =
<xsl:value-of select="/notify/Blob/xml/TenderOffer/Shipment/ShipmentStop[StopSequence='1']/DepartureTime/EventTime/PlannedTime/GLogDate"/>